# Can't send message to SignalR Hub from JavaScript while rendering animation (requestAnimationFrame)

Tags: javascript, signalr, requestanimationframe

I have extremly simple game, client implemented with JS and SignalR server. 
The problem appears when I an trying to send message to SignalR' Hub while rendering animation with help of [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), when I send messages out of requestAnimationFrame loop it works perfectly.

```
var main = function () {

update(); //Update game objects
$.connection.gameHub.server.setState(id, player.x, player.y);

render(); //Render scene

requestAnimationFrame(main);
};
```

My question is: Am I allowed to do some extra work while rendering, in case no what is the best way to implement rendering and comunication?

Comment: It should be perfectly possible, What problem do you face ?